# Is there a more pythonic way to format a string with a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using this approach to format a string with a dictionary. I was wondering, if for a conditional present dictionary key like 'Note', is this type of formatting good as a pythonic approach?

```
desc = "{Voce} {notes}".format(**spesa, notes='({Note})'.format(**spesa))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of result.

Comment: You could make it shorter, for example: `desc = "{0} {notes}".format(**spesa, notes=**spesa)`. Also take a look at [PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: Sorry, i'm not explaining good, my goal is to concatenate a string starting from a dictionary and add the parenthesis on 'Note' key value, without using an if to check the dictionary

Comment: @VirtApp could you provide us with an example output?